# Oclif with yarn workspaces

Tags: typescript, heroku, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, oclif

I have a node / typescript application that leverages yarn workspaces.  We are also using oclif for our cli.

I want to set up an architecutre where my main cli can leverge cli-plugins from the domains

```
\domains
    \emailService
        package.json
        \emailServiceCLIPlugin
           package.json
    \authenationService 
        package.json
        \AuthenticationServiceCLIPlugin
           package.json
\cli (my mainCLI)
   package.json. <--- in here I would like to plugin in the above two CLIPlugin packages
```

Is this possible?  Or there there another good pattern that I can put into effect to get the commands from these domain libraries into my core CLI

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

You just need to add a glob pattern in your root package.json workspaces setting.  then you can reference your package in the cli plugin array

Comment: somewhat related but have you tried running the ``oclif-dev pack`` command on the monorepo? can't seem to get it to work and there's an issue with no response https://github.com/oclif/oclif/issues/145